# Windows 7 service pack 1 does not get installed

Tags: windows-7, updates, service-pack

I must install windows 7 service pack 1, for that I go to control panel and from "windows update" when I select service pack 1 update, I get the following message for long time and nothing happens.

[image]

The hard disk light on the laptop is continuously ON and in the "resource monitor"  entry "MsMpEng.exe" shows around 60 hard faults/sec

then following message is shown

[image]

Then hard disk light is normal

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit OS or 32 bit OS?

Comment: @vembutech Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Run this tool and check. System Update Readiness Tool for Windows 7 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20858

Comment: the error code means ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, the Update Servers have trouble with Service Packs due to their size. To get around this problem download the service pack individually from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842

This includes 32 & 64bit versions. Just run the executable once downloaded. The service pack will install. Then you can re-run microsoft update to carry on with the updates.

Comment: Thank you so much, pls can you also help me with choosing the correct update for my system from the link that you have provided, I have Intel Pentium CPU P6200 2.13GHz

Comment: For 64 bit Windows choose: windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe

Comment: For 64 bit Windows choose: windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe - it's the 2nd from the bottom. Not symbols or anything else. Just the one mentioned